# How to Format Json Date and Bind it to The DatePicker Control

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, datepicker, momentjs

I have array of data in json:

```
[{"AccountStatementID": 2,"CompanyID": 1,"Description": "test","Amount": 1000,"ReceiptDate": "/Date(1447261200000)/","Type": "Payment"}];
```

I have successfully load the data into a table and display the ReceiptDate in the correct format `(dd/MM/yyyy)`. When I clicked edit button the ReceiptDate in the DatePicker control is still `/Date(1447261200000)/`.

I have formatted using momentjs in the following way:

```
ReceiptDate: moment(self.ReceiptDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Furthermore, the datepicker doesn't appear.

Why does the ReceiptDate not formatted, how to solve it and bring up the datepicker?

Here is the demo in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qdh9jw94/7/).

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you have set your date picker to read-only. That was the reason the datepicker was not appearing when there was a click.

I modified some minute details in your fiddle and ended up with this
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/karthikrp/52xLsmqL/1/).

One was saving Javascript date time object in your data since you are calling moment and formatting it.

```
var data = [
  {
    "AccountStatementID": 2,
    "CompanyID": 1,
    "Description": "test",
    "Amount": 1000,
    "ReceiptDate": new Date(1447261200000),
    "Type": "Payment"
  }
];
```

I couldn't figure out where you were setting the date while editing. So calling moment().format() will get you the required format while editing  too. (Remove readonly to date while editing if required).

Comment: I set readonly because I want to get the date value from the (calendar)datepicker. If you click add link, and click the receipt date textbox, it will display the calendar. From the link that you give, the calendar still doesn't appear

Comment: I have not removed readonly for updating existing data.
Click on 'Add New Statement of Accounts' and then click on Enter Receipt Date.

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach` loops over `AccountStatements`, which you populate with raw data:

```
var data = [
    {
        "AccountStatementID": 2,
        "CompanyID": 1,
        "Description": "test",
        "Amount": 1000,
        "ReceiptDate": "/Date(1447261200000)/",
        "Type": "Payment"
    }
];
```

...

```
self.AccountStatements = ko.observableArray(data);
```

When you click on edit, one record of that raw data that is sent to the edit function, and you set it as the value of `$root.AccountStatement`:

```
    self.AccountStatement(accountStatement);
```

So your editor is just working on raw data. At some point in the process you  need to convert your raw data into something like you created for the individual private variable

```
var AccountStatement
```

I would recommend you create a function that takes a raw data record and returns something of that form. Use it to transform your input array before assigning `self.AccountStatements`.